# Confusing .NoClassDefFoundError with packages

Tags: java, class, runtime, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

My code compiles successfully but will not run. Here is the relevant code.
I compile with "javac -cp .:/Users/DavidOwens/javacv-bin/* ICGPixelGetter.java" and the javacv-bin is located in my user folder.

```
    //Takes a video file and gets frame grabs of it
    private ArrayList<ImageView> getFrameGrabs() {
        try{
            //get video frames
            FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("for david.mpeg");

            g.start();

            for (int i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                ImageIO.write(g.grab().getBufferedImage(), "jpg", 
                    new File("frame-dump/video-frame-" 
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
                }

            g.stop();
            }

            catch( Exception ex ){
                System.out.println( "Frame Grab IOException");
            }
        return frameGrabs;
    }//END METHOD
```

and the major application start method

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;

@Override //Override start method in Application class
public void start( Stage primaryStage ) { 

    getFrameGrabs();

    //bunch of code that works fine
}
```

I get this stacktrace

```
    Exception in Application start method
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber
    at ICGPixelGetter.getFrameGrabs(ICGPixelGetter.java:112)
    at ICGPixelGetter.start(ICGPixelGetter.java:57)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: How you compile is not relevant. It's how you **run** that matters.

Comment: @JBNizet When i run the program through my terminal with just "java filename" i get this error. How do you recommend I run it differently?

Comment: Well, your class depends on classes that are under `.` and on all the jars that are under `.:/Users/DavidOwens/javacv-bin/`. So, just like when you compile, the current directory and the jars must be in the classpath: `java -cp .:/Users/DavidOwens/javacv-bin/* ICGPixelGetter`. It's a terrible practice to put your classes in the default package, BTW.

Comment: Note that java doesn't expect a file name. It expects the fully quelified name of the main class. So if your class is Foo and is under the package com.mycompany, it should be `java -cp ... com.mycompany.Foo`.

Comment: Apologies, @JBNizet this is my first venture into using libraries and the like. Why is it good practice to put my classes into a new package?

Comment: Because if everybody did like you, all the classes would be in the default package, and there would be thousands of name clashes. Also, classes in the default packages can't be imported by classes in packages, cause trouble when being dynamically loaded, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet So if i understand correctly, 1. move all relevant jar's to their own folder 2. compile with classpath referencing this folder 3. run with the classpath also?

Comment: Yes, except the classpath must contain all the jars, not just the folder containing it. That's what the `*`in `/Users/DavidOwens/javacv-bin/*` does.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a IDE to compile etc? You have to include the library into youre project.

Answer (score 0):

Does `javacv-bin/` contain a bunch of JAR files that you want included in your classpath? If not, you have the wrong syntax for your classpath. The syntax you show includes all class trees rooted in `./` and all JAR files contained in `javacv-bin/`. `.class` files found within `javacv-bin/` will not be found.

You will find http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html useful. Always RTM.

Also, the Java code you showed us will not compile. Please provide a full, if stripped-down, example as advised in http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Also,  you should have your classes in packages.

Comment: Yes the javacv-bin contains the jar file to handle the FFmpegFrameGrabber